# Java Spring JdbcTemplate where Clause not working

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I'm struggling writing a simple sql statement using JdbcTemplate.  The where clause is simply not working.

```
private static final String SELECT_CLAUSE =
        "SELECT count(*) " +
        "FROM AUSSCHUETTUNG_AUD " +
        "WHERE rev = 20008907 ";

Integer count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject( SELECT_CLAUSE, Integer.class );
```

The result of the count is 0, instead of 1.

Without where clause, the count is 1200.

The column rev has a value of 20008907.

When I do change the where clause as follow "where 1=1", then 1200 is returned.

The DB is Oracle (oracle driver version 8).

Here is the output when running the sql in "Oracle SQL DEVELOPER"

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, "not working"? Are you getting an error? Which data type is `rev`?

Comment: What's rev column type?

Comment: What is the count when you run the query directly in the database

Comment: The rev column is of type  NUMBER(19,0)

Comment: when I run the command directly on the DB, I get the followng result :   count(*) = 1

Comment: Are u connecting to the **same** database in java as you do in sql developer ?

Comment: Try to rewrite the SQL statement as one line from scratch, maybe you have invalid unseen character

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the reason why the where clause was not working...... I was connecting to a different DB from within the application.  My mistake..... :-(